# No Default Proposal in Eclipse C++ 2022-06

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

After updating to **Eclipse C++ 2022-06** there is `No Default Proposals` when I press `CTRL+Space`. See the below image. I went through all posts in SO regarding this issue but nothing helped. The option is enabled, I re-indexed several times the whole project. No change.

[image]

---

**BUT:**
When I click on a symbol while pressing the `CTRL` key then the editor jumps to the definition of the symbol, this means, Eclipse *knows* the symbol but it just for some reasons rejects to show the proposals. Also only clicking on the symbol immediately marks the definition/declaration.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the update Eclipse apperantly messed up the settings. I fixed it like this:

> Window | Preferences | `<filter for editor>` | C/C++ | Editor | Content
> Assist | Advanced

Enable `Parsing-based Proposals`

[image]